# How can I refresh the recyclerview from my fragment inside the activity using a custom dialog?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

So I have an activity that has 2 fragments in it one fragment contains a data from firebase and inside the activity I have a custom dialog for sorting the price using `rangeseekbar` a library. What I want to do is if i clicked the yes button on my custom dialog the `recyclerview` from the fragment will be refreshed and sort the data on it by the way I know how to sort the data using the method from firebase `startAt` and `endAt`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write a public method in your fragment that sort data and call a method from your activity.

In your `Fragment`

```
public void yourMethodName(){
//sort Code
}
```

In your `Activity`

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.yourMethodName();
```

**OR**

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
fragment.yourMethodName();
```

Comment: I aslo tried this code . but i get an error that on a null object reference.i aslo tried with getSupportFragmentManager().but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can create a call back Interface in your activity
  public interface OnSortOptionSelectedListener {
    public void onSortOptionClicked();
   }

 // Within your Activity
    OnSortOptionSelectedListener onSortOptionSelectedListener;

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    FragmentNameWithRecyclerView yourFragment = new FragmentNameWithRecyclerView();
    onSortOptionSelectedListener = (FragmentNameWithRecyclerView) yourFragment;
    adapter.addFragment(yourFragment, "SOME TITLE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


  // whenever sort option is clicked
  onSortOptionSelectedListener.onSortOptionClicked();

 // Your Fragment with RecyclerView will implement this interface

    public class FragmentNameWithRecyclerView extends Fragment implements 
  OnSortOptionSelectedListener  
  {

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
  @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    // Make sure you have the recyclerview initilialized properly here  

    return view;   
   }

   @Override
  public void onSortOptionClicked()
 {
 // Handle the logic to refresh the recyclerview here
 }

 }
```

Comment: What is the fragmentInstance?

Comment: `Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    FragmentNameWithRecyclerView yourFragment = new FragmentNameWithRecyclerView();
    onSortOptionSelectedListener = (FragmentNameWithRecyclerView) yourFragment;
    adapter.addFragment(yourFragment, "SOME TITLE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); ` Have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do your

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

in your main thread like in your onCreate, since you don't have the data required to display your recyclerview, you have to either set it up with dummy data first or, more preferably, don't display it yet, display a progress bar first to tell the user that it is not yet done loading.

after sorting your data you can call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
```